# Error Opening File?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, python-2.7, runtimeerror, spreadsheet

I have searched the internet for a few hours now and have gotten to the point where I need to ask this. I am currently developing a code that will take a large subdirectory of .xlsx files, read them through line by line, find data in those files, and compare said data with a master data list I have already created (this is part of a larger project, but I'm doing things one at a time.) I also apologize if parts of the code seem wacky, I've been experimenting. The code is below:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

path = os.getcwd()
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
gdb = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(path, 'excelconversion')
excel_files = path + '\\excel_files'
arcpy.env.workspace = excel_files
files = arcpy.ListFiles('*.xlsx')

#input file
shapefile = path + '\\micro_points-072810.shp'
field_list = ['MICRORREGI', 'X_field', 'Y_field']
Master_list = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile, field_list) as scur:
    #Loop through list of points
for each_row in scur:
    Master_list = [each_row[0], each_row[1], each_row[2]]


for each_file in files:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(each_file, 'MICRO') as data:
          for rows in data:
            print rows
    arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(each_file, 'table.gdb')
```

The current error that I keep receieving is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Y:\folder\user\Assignments\Assignment_5\Assignment_5.py", line30, in <module>
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(str(each_file), 'MICRO') as data:
RuntimeError: cannot open 'Product_34_Top_50.xlsx'
```

Comment: Have you try xls format?

Comment: A search cursor will not open a spreadsheet. It may open a page within a spreadsheet, if the page is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are jumping the gun on the usage of `SearchCursor`.

`files` is simply a [list of strings of file paths](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfiles.htm).

`arcpy.da.SearchCursor` expects a string for the `in_table` argument but in the schema of either a ['...feature class, layer, table, or table view.'](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/searchcursor.htm)

Instead of a string of a feature class, layer, table, or table view, you are passing a realtive, system, file path string to 'SearchCursor'.  It is telling you, "I don't know how to open this the *table* called 'Product_34_Top_50.xlsx'", not the file.

You first need to convert the file to a table which you actually do after the line that throws the error.

Without testing it for myself, I think you just need to literally swap the last line with the block before.

```
for each_file in files:
    arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(each_file, 'table.gdb')
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('table.gdb', 'MICRO') as data:
          for rows in data:
            print rows
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped clear things up a bit. It makes a little bit more sense now.